# Export to Excel in Office UI Fabric

Tags: office365, office-ui-fabric

Is there any export to excel feature for **Office UI Fabric** List by default, i couldn't find it in the Official Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is currently no functionality for this. Office-ui-fabric is a *user interface* library that concerns itself primarily with user experience design (UX), not functionality.